# Automatically Putting The Download Link Based on The Name

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a worksheet which contains list of name. I need to put the link to the file which belongs to each name. Let's say the name is ALPHA CHARLIE then the file name which belongs to him is ALPHA_CHARLIE.pdf. So, Here is my worksheet looks like:

[image: WORKSHEET]

What should I do to automatically place the link to each of the name? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have an Excel tag when you are using LibreOffice Calc?

Comment: My mistake, I'm currently using Ubuntu but my actual work is in the Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two tasks for this. First is making the link
for the left hand side we can use text

- http://download.com/

give it a name in the name manager of LT (the name manger is on the formula ribbon)

for the right side we need to replace the space with an underscore and add a .pdf to the end

- =+SUBSTITUTE($B2," ","_")&".pdf"

Give it a name of RT using the name manger

in the C column

- =+HYPERLINK(LT&RT)

will give the link.

If you do not like using names, then in the c column use

- =HYPERLINK("http://download.com/"&SUBSTITUTE($B2," ","_")&",pdf")

as a single step formula